# How to build below design using columns in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have used following strategy: Dividing it into two equal columns col-md-6. Again splitting col-md-6 into 3 columns each i.e. col-md-4. Same for right side. but problem occurs that how to do even spacing between columns on right side.

[image]

My code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <p>My Earning</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <h5>100</h5>
                <p>Number of Notes Sold</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <h5>$10,000</h5>
                <p>Money Earned</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <h5>38</h5>
                <p>My Downloads</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h5>12</h5>
                <p>My Rejected Notes</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 data">
                <h5>102</h5>
                <p>Buyer Requests</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is to insert **EMPTY** table cells in-between with fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your design I just created the same kind of layout. I used grid-based we can use flex also.
I added the gutter also.

I think this will help you.

```css
.row div div{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
}
.row .no-gutters{
padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 no-gutters">
      <div>one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 no-gutters">
      <div>two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div>three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div>four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div>five</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```